# C++ simple string program

Tags: c++, string

beginner here

i wrote the below in C++, it's a short program that currently takes 2 words as inputs, and outputs the same words back but the words are split into even and odd instead. I would like to be able to do this for 'T' words instead, but I can't figure it out. I would like to be able to first input the number of words that will follow, for example 10. Then to input the words and get T results back. So instead of just 2 words, an unlimited amount with the user specifying.

I need to put the below into a function and go from there sometime, but I want to learn the best technique to do so - any advice please?

Thanks!
Alex

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;

    string FirstWord;
    cin >> FirstWord;
    int LengthFirst;
    LengthFirst = FirstWord.length();        
    string EvenFirst;
    string OddFirst;
    for (int i = 0; i < LengthFirst; i += 2){
        EvenFirst = EvenFirst + FirstWord[i];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < LengthFirst; i += 2){
        OddFirst = OddFirst + FirstWord[i];
    }
    string SecondWord;
    cin >> SecondWord;
    int LengthSecond;
    LengthSecond = SecondWord.length();
    string EvenSecond;
    string OddSecond;
    for (int i = 0; i < LengthSecond; i += 2){
        EvenSecond += SecondWord[i];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < LengthSecond; i += 2){
        OddSecond += SecondWord[i];
    }

    cout << EvenFirst << " " << OddFirst << endl;
    cout << EvenSecond << " " << OddSecond << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by split even-odd? are you printing all of the even-index words [0,2,4,...] then all of the odd-index words [1,3,5,...]?]

Comment: printing all of the even-index letters, then all of the odd-index letters.
for example if input was

stack
overflow

output would be
sak tc
oefo vrlw

Comment: Do read and store a bunch of words you can use a vector. Take a look at the answer to this question: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/14792/

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it here, I was over-thinking this one

I put it in a for loop, as below - so any number of words can be input, user has to input the number of test cases at the

```html
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
        string FirstWord;
        cin >> FirstWord;
        int LengthFirst;
        LengthFirst = FirstWord.length();        
        string EvenFirst;
        string OddFirst;
        for (int i = 0; i < LengthFirst; i += 2){
            EvenFirst = EvenFirst + FirstWord[i];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < LengthFirst; i += 2){
            OddFirst = OddFirst + FirstWord[i];
        }
        cout << EvenFirst << " " << OddFirst << endl;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's true, but you also are not storing these words, which appeared to be part of the requirements you established originally: "Then to input the words and get T results back."

Comment: it is perfeclty ok to answer your own question. However as unclear as the question is, it is also not really clear what problem your answer is solving. I would suggest to at least add an example of input and output and desired input and output to the question

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you are performing the same task *N* times.

First, let's discuss how to store the information. Functionally, we have one string as input which yields two strings as output. `std::pair` (from `<utility>`) lets us easily represent this. But for sake of even-odd, `std::array` might be a better representation for us. Since we have a variable number of words as input, a variable number of `std::array` will be output. `std::vector` (from `<vector>`) is our friend here.

Second, let's discuss how to process the information. Using named variables for each output component does not scale, so let's switch to a fixed array (noted below as `array<string,2>`. By switching to a fixed array for output, addressing each split becomes a function of the loop index (`index % 2`). Below is a solution that generalizes on a known split size at compile time.

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int N;
  std::cin >> N;

  constexpr const int Split = 2;
  using StringPack = std::array<std::string, Split>;
  std::vector<StringPack> output;
  for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < N; ++wordIndex) {
    std::string word;
    std::cin >> word;
    StringPack out;
    {
      int index = 0;
      for (char c : word) {
        out[index % Split] += c;
        ++index;
      }
    }
    output.emplace_back(out);
  }
  for (const auto & out : output) {
    for (const auto & word : out) {
      std::cout << word << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```